# Anyway to reset svn cached auths for a specific repo?

Tags: batch-file, svn, caching, tortoisesvn

I've been searching all over for this and I'm surprised I haven't found it yet.

I'm using Windows 7.
I've got TortoiseSVN 1.8 with command line tools available but if there is a solution using another client that will work, I'm open to other options.

I'm trying to reset the cached auths for a specific repository on an svn client.

I've have a group of projects (~15) that get built all together.  We have setup batch files using the svn command line client to checkout and build the projects which work great on the individual developers machine since the svn client caches their credentials.

However, we are setting up a central build machine for releases (instead of having one person responsible for release builds) and we would like for anyone to be able to login and run a build using their own credentials.

The problem we have is that if we leave the svn client using it's default settings, then anyone logging into the machine will use the previous person's credentials.  If we switch the svn client to not cache credentials, then the build process (its all scripted remember) has to prompt for every project which results in the user typing their password ~15 times just to do a build.

We are part of a large company and our svn server houses a lot of different repos for other teams and some developers use multiple repos so I cannot simply clear the cache directory after the build because that would wipe out all cached repos instead of just ours (as far as I can tell, svn only caches by server, not by repo).

Is there any solution I can implement that will prompt for svn credentials on the first project that gets pulled from svn in the batch file, uses those credentials for all projects in the script but then clears the cached credentials for only those projects (or the whole repo) when the script finishes?

I've tried several different method to try and "reset" the credentials for a specific project but I am not having any luck.  Even if my script has to go reset them individually, that would be ok.

Someone on another so thread suggested using svn switch on the project and providing a different user via --username when done but that doesn't seem to work on windows (they were using OSX).  The next time I run the script, it simply defaults to the last authenticated user.

-edit- added a dumbed down version of the script:

```
@ECHO OFF
pushd %~dp0

SET SVN=https://domain.com:81/svn/repo
SET TAG=%1

CALL :GET_PROJECT_TAG project1
CALL :GET_PROJECT_TAG project2
CALL :GET_PROJECT_TAG project3
CALL :GET_PROJECT_TAG project4
CALL :GET_PROJECT_TAG project5
CALL :GET_PROJECT_TAG project6
GOTO :END

:GET_PROJECT_TAG
svn export %SVN%/%1/tags/%TAG%/ %TAG%/%1/
EXIT /B

:END
popd
PAUSE
```

-end edit-

thoughts?

Comment: For a build or continuous integration machine I would recommend creating a **new dedicated user** which is given read only access to the SVN repositories and then set that user as the only account to be used on that machine.  Does everyone log into this new box using the same generic user or do they use their own users via LDAP?  I ask this to know if the build computer already knows who is executing the script.  Also, it would be helpful to post your current script to show exactly how the SVN repositories are being handled.

Comment: @DavidRuhmann The dedicated user for svn access on the machine is an answer we have considered.  To answer your questions:  Yes everyone uses a single login for the build machine (hence why we would like to secure the svn access better).  I've added a basic version of the script.  There is quite a bit of complexity not shown above that actually prompt the user for information if not supplied by the command line as well as differentiating release builds from dev builds and checking .pdb files back in after the build is complete but in the end it all boils down to what is above.

Comment: What about having the batch script prompt for credentials if not defined?  Use `setlocal` just below `@echo off` to make the script forget the credentials on exit.  If you'd like to mask the input of the password, it can be done with a PowerShell command.  [See item #5 on this page](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/76911/59557) for an example.  Then just reuse `%pass%` in all svn commands as needed for as long as the script is running.  If you're prompted for auth info via a GUI, then might using [Subversion for Windows](http://alagazam.net/) instead of TortoiseSVN solve your problems?

Comment: @rojo I think that may well be a solution (combining it with svn's --no-auth-cache flag).  I had previously dismissed that idea because I didn't think there was a way to mask the password prompt but the powershell method (which should be installed on every Win7 machine) should work fine.  If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about having the batch script prompt for credentials if not defined? Use `setlocal` just below `@echo off` to make the script forget the credentials on exit. If you'd like to mask the input of the password, it can be done with a PowerShell command.

```
<NUL set /P "=Password? "
set "psCommand=powershell -command "$p=read-host -AsSecureString;^
$m=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal];$m::PtrToStringAuto($m::SecureStringToBSTR($p))""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set "pass=%%p"

echo You entered %pass%
```

Then just reuse `%pass%` in all svn commands as needed for as long as the script is running. If you're prompted for auth info via a GUI, then might using [Subversion for Windows](http://alagazam.net/) instead of TortoiseSVN solve your problems?

**Edit:** I feel I should note that it's not unreasonable to expect special characters in passwords that could potentially break your script.  Whenever you retrieve the `%pass%` variable, you should probably do so in the delayed expansion style to prevent characters like `^` and `<` from being evaluated.  **But don't enable delayed expansion until retrieval.**  If delayed expansion is enabled during the input, exclamation marks might be stripped.  Do it like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

<NUL set /P "=Password? "
set "psCommand=powershell -command "$p=read-host -AsSecureString;^
$m=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal];$m::PtrToStringAuto($m::SecureStringToBSTR($p))""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set "pass=%%p"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo You entered !pass!
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of batch files that I use to temporarily clear the cached credentials.  You could easily modify them to suit your particular needs.

```
:: ClearCachedCredentials.bat
:: 2015-10-30 Kurt Schultz - Tested on Windows 7, 64-bit
:: Move the current TortoiseSVN credential cache files to a backup folder.
:: This allows you to log on to Subversion using a different set of credentials.
:: The original credentials can be restored by running RestoreCachedCredentials.bat
::
:: Alternatively, you can open the individual files in the svn.simple folder using
:: a text editor and look for the user ID that you want to remove from the cache.
:: Remove or delete the file as needed.

@set filePath=\Users\%username%\Application Data\Subversion\auth
@set fileCount=0
@If not exist "C:%filePath%" (
    @echo Cannot locate "C:%filePath%"
    @echo Do you have Tortoise SVN installed?
) Else (
    @C:
    @CD "%filePath%"
    @for /f %%A in ('dir /b /a-d "svn.simple\*" 2^>nul ^| find /v /c "" ') do @set /a fileCount+=%%A
    @Rem When the dir command is issued from the command line, there must be a space between the carat and the pipe e.g. ^ |
    @Rem or you will get an error, invalid switch - "v".  When inside the "for" command, the space cannot be there.
)

:: I had to move the following section out of the section above in order to test the value of fileCount.
:: When it was inside the Else block above, the value was always 0.
@If %fileCount%==0 (
    @echo There were no cached files to backup or clear.
) Else (
    @dir svn.simple
    @echo.
    @echo These credentials will be moved to the backup folder.
    @echo.
    @echo Press Ctrl-C now to abort or
    @pause
)

:: I had to move the following section out of the section above and into its own If condition
:: in order to get the Ctrl-C to work correctly.  (The file move did not occur, but the echo
:: statements were still executed.
@If Not %fileCount%==0 (
    @If not exist backup (
       @md backup
       )

    @If not exist backup\svn.simple (
       @md backup\svn.simple
       )

    @move svn.simple\*.* backup\svn.simple
    @echo.
    @echo The TortoiseSVN credentials have been backed up and cleared.
    @echo Run RestoreCachedCredentials.bat to restore them.
)
@echo.
@pause


:: RestoreCachedCredentials.bat
:: 2015-10-30 Kurt Schultz - Tested on Windows 7, 64-bit
:: Restore the TortoiseSVN credential cache files from the backup folder.

@set continue=false
@set filePath=\Users\%username%\Application Data\Subversion\auth
@If not exist "C:%filePath%" (
    @echo Cannot locate "C:%filePath%"
    @echo Do you have Tortoise SVN installed?
) Else (
    @C:
    @CD "%filePath%"
    @If not exist backup\svn.simple (
    @Echo The backup directory does not exist.  There is nothing to restore.
    @Echo You must first use ClearCachedCredentials.bat to create a backup.
    ) Else (
    @echo This will restore the Subversion credentials from your backup folder.
    @echo Press Ctrl-C now to abort or
    @pause
    @set continue=true
    )
)
@If %continue%==true (
    @copy backup\svn.simple\*.* svn.simple
    @echo.
    @echo The TortoiseSVN credentials have been restored.
)
@echo.
@pause
```